# How to best measure the inside gap of stairs

Tags: stairs, laminate

I’ve purchased sone pre-molded stair caps with integrated flooring to match my basement. They are expensive and i need to ensure I make the right cut. I’ve been struggling to accurately measure this gap. I have thought about getting some cheap plywood and measuring and cutting to create a template and use that to minimize any cutting errors. Looking for ideas to best do this please.

[image]

Comment: I like the template idea. Just make sure the template is accurate for each stair, don't assume it will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would measure the front and the back of each stair with a tape measure.   If they are the same you are in luck and you don't really need to do much other than make your cut.

If it is the end of summer where you live I would cut these pretty tight.   You should have to knock them into place - not forcefully.   If it is the end of winter however I would leave a 1/8" gap - 1/16" on each side to allow for expansion.

If you stairs are not square I wouldn't rely on a template - I would measure and map out each tread.   In years of doing houses I have ran into this twice out of 100+... and both times I could have told you that there were issue (settling caused stairs to be completely off level on older historic house).

Comment: The flooring is laminate - do i need to still need to make it tight?

Comment: Yes.   Would be good to see the specs on this or some pictures.   Do you have a link to this?

Comment: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Home-Decorators-Collection-Noble-Oak-7-5-in-L-x-47-6-in-W-Luxury-Vinyl-Plank-Flooring-24-74-sq-ft-case-446128/300253422

Comment: you seem to be making unfounded assumptions about seasonal humidity variations. some places have dry summers and wet winters.

Comment: @Jasen - i get that.   I am sure there is variance.   But dry/wet is not humidity.  Humidity is a measure of moisture in the cold air cannot hold as much moisture.   A wet winter is less humid than a dry summer on 90%+ of the earth.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the dew oint has much bearing on this.